# How do I disable the battery water level sensor on watchdog sump pump back up when I replace it with a sealed battery?

Tags: basement

I am replacing my sump pum back up battery with a sealed battery.  What do I do with the battery level water sensor?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. A picture of the battery water level sensor would help understand what you're talking about.

Comment: The model and type would be helpful, I have done this with a simple resistor to fake the system when using optima batteries that don't have a liquid level.

Answer (score 2):

If it's a basement watchdog, you can attach the sensor rod to the positive battery terminal to disable it.